# When I execute '~/.zshrc' in the VS code terminal I get 'permission denied'. What is a good solution?

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh

I know that I can run VS Code as root but I don't want to give it those privileges.

I know that I can chmod 777 the `/zshrc` file, but I've heard that that is almost a bad idea.

What is in a good solution to this problem and why is it good?

Comment: What do you mean with “execute”? Can you please update your question with what it is exactly that you are doing?

Comment: How do you "execute" the file? I hope you don't try to type into your command line a verbatim command `~/.zshrc`.....

Comment: `.zshrc` should be *sourced* by an existing shell, not executed as a script.

Comment: @user1934428: That’s what I did, yes. Not feeling great about it after these comments though :-)

Comment: It is not **forbidden** in that nobody will shoot you for doing it. I just don't see a reason for doing it. In general, if you want to execute a script as its own process, the command must either have executable permision **and** a valid #! line, **or** you have to invoke it explicitly via the script processor, i.e. `zsh foo` for a zsh-script _foo_  and `tclsh bar` for a Tcl-script _bar_.